# Mongoose save await throws error called level error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
async add(data) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let model = new Model();
        model.name = data.name;

        try {
            await mainCategory.save();

            resolve(true);
        } catch (err) {   
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

i have written a code like thise to save the data to mongodb using mongoose it's throwing a error like this

```
{
   "level": "error"
}
```

This error is given from the catch.

This is my Schema of the model

```
let category = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    imageUrl
  },
  subCategories: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'SubCategory'
  }]
});
```

Comment: `"level": "error"` is very specific to your model. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , only you may know why it's there. Did you try to inspect `err`? It should be something more than plain object. Also, the thing you're doing is promise construction antipattern. Never use `new Promise` when you have a promise. Never use `async` as `Promise` callback.

Comment: @estus i have added my schema

Comment: The schema doesn't explain what's wrong. You didn't clarify anything about the error. How did you inspect it. A screenshot from attached debugger would help. It's not a known Mongoose error. At this point your problem is unsolvable. Please, provide MCVE that allows other users to  the problem - a repo, anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
async add(data){
    model.name = data.name;
    let  model = new Model();
    model.save()
    .then(callback => {
        console.log(callback)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

Try this
```

Comment: Can you please add more details on why this would resolve the issue ?

Comment: Have you tried it.. and your schema design is not okay.. redesign your schema

Comment: ````
let category = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
   type: String
  },
  subCategories: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'SubCategory'
  }
});